# Enterprise Library 6 Validation for WCF: Custom Validator Error Message

Tags: c#, wcf, validation, enterprise-library

I am using Enterprise Library 6 Validation in WCF. I have made a Custom Validator. When I use it I specify a `MessageTemplate`. When error Occurs, instead of showing `MessageTemplate` it shows the message given in `DoValidate` of the custom validator.

**Custom Validator**

```
public sealed class EmailValidatorAttribute : ValidatorAttribute
{
    protected override Validator DoCreateValidator(Type targetType)
    {
        return new EmailValidator();
    }
}

public sealed class EmailValidator : Validator
{
    public EmailValidator()
        : base("Email Validation", "String")
    {
    }
    protected override string DefaultMessageTemplate
    {
        get { return "Email Validation"; }
    }
    // This method does the actual validation
    public override void DoValidate(object objectToValidate, object currentTarget, string key, ValidationResults validationResults)
    {
        Regex emailRegex = new Regex(IConnect.DataContract.WCFServiceResources.EmailRegex);
        Match match = emailRegex.Match((string)objectToValidate);
        if (!match.Success)
        {
            LogValidationResult(validationResults, "Invalid Email Address.", currentTarget, key);
        }
    }
}
```

**WCF**

```
[OperationContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(ValidationFault))]
string EmailAddressCheck([EmailValidator(MessageTemplate = "Enter a Valid Email ID.")]string email);
```

> Currently it is showing **"Invalid Email Address."** defined in
>   **DoValidate** of Custom Validator Code

But

> I want to show **"Enter a Valid Email ID."** defined in **MessageTemplate** in WCF Code

How to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found answer to my question.

```
public override void DoValidate(
    object objectToValidate,
    object currentTarget,
    string key,
    ValidationResults validationResults)
{
    Regex emailRegex = new Regex(IConnect.DataContract.WCFServiceResources.EmailRegex);
    Match match = emailRegex.Match((string)objectToValidate);
    if (!match.Success)
    {
        LogValidationResult(
           validationResults,
           // The next line does the trick
           string.Format(this.MessageTemplate, new object[] { objectToValidate }),
           currentTarget,
           key);
    }
}
```

The part in `LogValidationResult` that does the trick is:

```
string.Format(this.MessageTemplate, new object[] { objectToValidate })
```